# CSS Dropdown Menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm learning to style a dropdown menu and have a couple of questions.

You can see the dropdowns here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomperkins/3M7Cb/

**My questions are:**

1. How can I get a down arrow to
   appear on each parent item (when I
   tried it replaced the background
   properties).
2. How can I get the whole child
   area to be clickable, rather than
   just the text itself?

As always, all help really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tom Perkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the down arrow, my inclination is to use a text-object rather than an image:

```
ul li.top:after {
content: "▼";
}
```

To make the whole `li` clickable:

```
ul li a {
    display: block;
    /* other stuff */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo of both suggestions](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3M7Cb/1/).

---

**Edited** to adjust the hover style of the down-arrow:

```
ul li.top:after {
    color: #000;
    content: "▼";
    float: right;
}

ul:hover li.top:after {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3M7Cb/2/)

Comment: @Tom Perkins: it's no problem at all, you're quite welcome =)

Answer (score 0):

question 2> your `<a>` tag needs to be rendered as a block that takes up the area of the dropdown item. Since you are using a specialized tool to build these menus, I'm guessing there is a config setting (or similar) that allows you to set this up.